# Is this form of bayes rule valid?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, bayes-theorem

In the bayes rule, does \begin{equation}
 \Pr((A\mid B)\mid C)
\end{equation}

have a meaning? is it a valid form of a probability? if $(A\mid B)$ ( I do not mean $\Pr(A\mid B)$ ) is an event, the aforementioned form of bayes rule would be legal. If yes, then in

\begin{equation}
 \Pr((A\mid B)\mid C)=\frac{\Pr((A\mid B),C)}{\Pr(C)}
\end{equation}

is there any trick to calculate $\Pr((A\mid B),c)$?

P.S: $A,B,C$ are dependent to each other.

Comment: Isn't it equivalent to $P(A|B\cap C)$? If you want to compute the conditional probability, you "assume" that $C$ happens and then that $B$ happens. Therefore $B\cap C$ happens. This is my understanding... Of course, I would like to see a real justification.

Comment: I remember this exact question being asked a while ago, and the exhausting discussion with the OP which ensued...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(A\mid C)$ is not an event.  It is a simple misunderstanding to think that $\Pr(A\mid C)$ is the probability of something called $A\mid C$ or $(A\mid C)$ or $A$ given $C$.  The expression $\Pr(A\mid C)$ is not the probability of something called $A$ given $C$.  Rather, it is the probability given $C$, of $A$.  Grammatically, one should not read it as being the thing you get when you put $A\mid C$ into $\Pr(\cdots)$, but rather as the thing you get when you put $A$ into $\Pr(\cdots\mid C)$.